# use mexCallMATLAB in cpp

Tags: c++, matlab

1-testmex.exe is the name of our project and exception error was occurred for our project in line

```
mexCallMATLAB(1, plhs, 1, prhs, "test_mex");
```

Sorry for duplicating name of our MEX file and the project. But, if we call any other MEX file, the exception error is still thrown.

2-If even lines after

```
mexCallMATLAB(1, plhs, 1, prhs, "test_mex");
```

is omitted, this exception error is still thrown.

Let's  describe whole of work!

Step 1.  Create a matlab function as follow:

```
 function [y]= test(x)
    y = x^2;
 end
```

Step 2. Save it as test.m

step 3. Make MEX file with matlab coder. It yields a MEX file namely test_mex.mexw64.

step 4. Put test_mex.mexw64 in C++ project folder namely XYZ.

step 5. The source of the cpp file in project XYZ is:

```
void main(){
mxArray* plhs[1];
mxArray* prhs[1];
double *plhs_p,  *prhs_p;

prhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1, 1, mxREAL);
prhs_p = mxGetPr(prhs[0]);
plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1, 1, mxREAL);
cout << "enter number:" << endl;
cin >> prhs_p[0];
mexCallMATLAB(1, plhs, 1, prhs, "test_mex");
/*
mxDestroyArray(prhs[0]);
plhs_p = mxGetPr(plhs[0]);
cout << prhs_p[0] << "^2:" << endl;
cout << plhs_p[0] << endl;
mxDestroyArray(plhs[0]);*/
}
```

step 6. Compile and build XYZ successfully as a win64 project.

step 7. Run project XYZ.
Get an exception error in line

```
mexCallMATLAB(1, plhs, 1, prhs, "test_mex");
```

as follow:

"Unhandled exception at 0x00000000 in XYZ.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation at location 0x0000000000000000."

and now, we are confused about this error.

Comment: You are not initializing the MATLAB interpreter. You should follow the example here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/calling-matlab-software-from-a-c-application.html

Comment: mexCallMATLAB( ) is for mex functions only, not main code like this.  Mex functions have the gateway mexFunction( ) interface.  Main code like you have would typically interface via the MATLAB Engine.